# Android's ExpandableListView: Keep groups expanded/unexpanded when removing an item

Tags: android, refresh, expandablelistview

I have an activity with an ExpandableListView. I fill the list using a custom adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter (my adapter is called StopsExpandableAdapter). I implemented all the needed methods.

In my activity I can delete entries from that list using the context menu. When the user does it, I want to refresh the list so the item is removed. If I create a new adapter, the listview is reset to default and all the groups are collapsed. I want to keep the state of the listview, so expanded groups are still expanded after refreshing the list.

I thought I could do it adding a removeGroup method in my custom adapter (StopsExpandableAdapter) and use it in my activity after deleting the group, but if I use:

```
 mExpandableList.getAdapter();
```

I get a ExpandableListConnector, not my custom adapter, so I can't use my function. How can I refresh the list and keep its state?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this??

Comment: I just posted the solution I'm using :) I hope it works for you, I decided to just told you the idea instead of posting the code since I have an ExpandableList inside an ExpandableList and my code is kinda messy.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?? .. i have a problem like you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738932/keep-group-expanded-status-when-change-data-expandable-list-view/29739093#29739093 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access my adapter I save it as a global variable:

```
private StopsExpandableAdapter adapter;
```

This way I can access my function to remove a child from my data list (inside the adapter) and notify that the data has changed.

To be able to mantain the state I'm using booleans to know if a group has been expanded or not. Everytime I add or remove an item I check which groups are expanded to be able to expand them again after the add/remove has been done.

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> expandGroups;
```

Comment: Ok, I can able to expand the group using that boolean value. But it collapse first and then expand right? There should be a blinking effect In screen. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command.

> StopsExpandableAdapter.notify();

or

> StopsExpandableAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();