# Keep Group Expanded Status when change data expandable list view

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

When user click the group row, the children list is expanded and show. When i add any group item to Arraylist and call method **notifyDataSetChanged();**
Group Expanded Status wrong .. how to do fix

Example:
Current group position 1 (parent 2) is expanded.. When i add group parent 0 to first and call **notifyDataSetChanged();** . parent 2 is collapse and parent 1 is expanded. How to keep parent 2 expaded

[image]

Sorry my english not good.

Answer (score 0):

when you want add parent and of its children just before,

1.just take all current parents and their children in one temporarily list

2.clear current filled list.

3.add new parent and their children to list(that we clear).

4.now, add temporarily list to our current list(in which we add, new parent and their children)

5.now use new filled list to you expandable list adapter

6.clear your temporarily list.

Comment: i use this way to add new item, i use temparray, but i want to keep group item expanded status

Comment: means like if children in a view is currently opened and when we add new parent with their children than still view is opened with current status ?

Comment: can you give code of adapter, not function add item, i think some my method override getChild, getgroud, id or object have problems. Thank for help

Comment: refer this link, might be proved helpful to you                                                                   https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-expandablelistview-magic